# Ubuntu black screen and underscore at the top left corner on VirtualBox

Tags: boot, 20.04

It was working fine last time I used it. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 in vVirtualBox. After the Ubuntu logo has done loading a black screen with an underscore character appears.

[image]